# If else statement error in java

Tags: java

I am new to java programming and I am trying to program, however, I am getting an error in my If Else statement. Can someone please look into it and help me.

```
 public Effort getStep(int value) {
        if (value < mGreenStep)
            return Effort.GURU;
        else  (value < mYelloStep)
            return Effort.WALKING;

    }
}

I get an error which says error: ';' expected
```

Could someone please help me with this if else statement.

Comment: Please reformulate your post and ask a single, well-defined question.

Comment: "_to learn new stuff_" are you sure this app is the best to _learn_ ?

Comment: You don't need android studio or even android to do this. Read official api docs or make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a condition with the else statement, try with an `else if`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` (at least in the snippet you posted):

```
public Effort getStep(int value) {
  if (value < mGreenStep)
    return Effort.GURU;
  else  (value < mYelloStep)
    return Effort.WALKING;
  } // <-- this doesn't have a sibling!
}
```

You can probably just delete that line, or add `{` after the `else` statement.

As Emanuele points out, `else (...)` is also incorrect - you either just want `else` without a `(...)` conditional or you should use `else if (...)` (and then you'll probably want an *actual* `else` block after that.