# if else statement error as it says its not a statement

Tags: java

I am new to java programming and I am trying to program, however, I am getting an error in my If Else statement. Can someone please look into it and help me.

```
 public Effort getStep(int value) {
        if (value < mGreenStep)
            return Effort.GURU;
        else  (value < mYelloStep)
            return Effort.WALKING;

    }
}

I get an error which says error: ';' expected
```

Could someone please help me with this if else statement.

Comment: It's either just `else` without condition or `else if` with condition.

Comment: You got too much '}'

Comment: You aready asked this exact same question, with a different user name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626042/if-else-statement-error-in-java. Don't do that. Instead, improve your original question.

Comment: You probably want to replace `else` with `else if` and add a final `else` for values that are larger than both green and yellow values.

Comment: Marvin can you please rewrite the code for me so that I am able to discover in future what my error is.

Comment: assylias could you please rewwrite code so that I can learn next time.

Comment: @user8162255 Additional help here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html - read it, understand it and you will solve your problem on your own.

Comment: dude there is nothing to learn or post here an question. Read error message carefully. you have aditional `}`(thats a syntax error). And second one is `else  (value < mYelloStep)` you cannot add condtion to `else`, but you can add to `else if`. So change to  `else  if(value < mYelloStep)`. Please read a book.

Answer (score 2):

It's either just `else` without condition or `else if` with condition, see ["The if-then and if-then-else Statements"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Without condition:

```
public Effort getStep(int value) {
    if (value < mGreenStep)
        return Effort.GURU;
    else
        return Effort.WALKING;
}
```

With condition:

```
public Effort getStep(int value) {
    if (value < mGreenStep)
        return Effort.GURU;
    else if (value < mYelloStep)
        return Effort.WALKING;
    // missing default
}
```

Note that the second version will not compile either as you have declared to return an `Effort` but there is no branch that covers cases where neither `value < mGreenStep` nor `value < mYelloStep` is `true`, so you would need an additional `else` for that as well.

As a side note: While it is valid to use `if`/`else` statements without brackets (`{}`) it is strongly recommended to always include them:

```
public Effort getStep(int value) {
    if (value < mGreenStep) {
        return Effort.GURU;
    } else {
        return Effort.WALKING;
    }
}
```

(I'm ignoring the extra `}` in your code as this is probably only from copy&paste)

Answer (score 1):

In an if-else block, the else statement does not have a condition. If you would like to add a condition, change it to an if-else if statement.

```
else if (value < mYelloStep)
    return effort.WALKING;
else
    return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use else if (condn). In java if you use single else then it means none of the above conditions got satisfied but else is never followed by a condition unless you use else-if.

ie.

```
..
else if (value < mYellowStep)
return effort.WALKING;
}

simply use
..
else
 return effort.WALKING
}
```

Comment: What about a link? short code? specific pointing to where he was wrong in his code? These kind of things are more for comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have a condition after the else.

Try with `else if`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

your syntax for if-else is wrong there should be an if after the else. Here is the correct syntax for if-else statement

```
int testscore = 76;
char grade;

if (testscore >= 90) {
    grade = 'A';
} else if (testscore >= 80) {
    grade = 'B';
} else if (testscore >= 70) {
    grade = 'C';
} else if (testscore >= 60) {
    grade = 'D';
} else {
    grade = 'F';
}
```

in your code the correct syntax would be

```
public Effort getStep(int value) {
    if (value < mGreenStep)
        return Effort.GURU;
    else if (value < mYelloStep)
        return Effort.WALKING;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return null`, the OP may want to `throw new AssertionError("value should be < " + mYelloStep + " but received " + value);` or something like that (maybe an `IllegalArgumentException`).